# Reindexing a pandas DataFrame using a dict (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Is there a way, without use of loops, to reindex a `DataFrame` using a `dict`? Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]])
dic = {0:'first', 1:'second'}
```

I want to apply something efficient to `df` for obtaining:

```
        0  1
first   1  2
second  3  4
```

Speed is important, as the index in the actual `DataFrame` I am dealing with has a huge number of unique values. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the [rename](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) function:

```
df.rename(index=dic)

#       0   1
#first  1   2
#second 3   4
```

---

Modified the *dic* to get the results: `dic = {0:'first', 1:'second'}`